# How to instantiate object using Map of arguments and builder?

Tags: java

So I have an object, lets call it myObject

Here are the constructors to my object

```java
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
private static class myObject {

        public int argA = 1;
        public boolean argB;
        public int argC = 4;
        public int argD = 5;
        public String argE;
```

An API is giving me a list of arguments to create this object with

```java
Map<String, Object> objectParams = new HashMap<>();
objectParams.put(argA, 6)
objectParams.put(argC, 3)
objectParams.put(argE,"Hello")
myObject newObjectWithTheseParameters = ?;
```

How do I instantiate this object?
Whats the cleanest/ best way to instantiate this object given a map of arguments and a builder.

Comment: This is not likely to be very convenient at all.  Your best bet is to loop through the map, calling the appropriate setters.

Comment: But I dont want setters since I don't want the values to be able to be changed.

Comment: Add more details to your question, which libraries and frameworks do you use? How is the other API transferring the Map, just as a method call, or as Json/XML?

Comment: Use the setters of your builder, then, since you've mentioned there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a constructor in the `myObject` class that takes a Map?

```
private static class myObject {
    public int argA = 1;
    public boolean argB;
    public int argC = 4;
    public int argD = 5;
    public String argE;


    public myObject(int argA, boolean argB, int argC, int argD, String argE) {
        //...
    }

    public myObject(Map<String, Object> objectParams) {
        Integer argA;
        if(objectParams.contains('argA')) {
            argA = objectParams.get('argA') 
        } else {
            //default value or throw Exception
        }

        // ...similiar for argB, argC, argD, argE


        this(argA, argB, argC, argD, argE);
    }
}
```